# Falha de segmentação ao alterar valor de uma Struct em C

Tags: c

Está ocorrendo um erro `Falha de segmentação` ao tentar acessar informação de uma struct. O código é o seguinte

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int val;
}Info;

void inserir(Info*);

void main(){
    Info* info;
    inserir(info);

    //O erro acontece na linha de baixo, como se o
    //que foi feito na função inserir não persistiu de fato
    //na estrutura
    printf("%d\n", info->val);

}

void inserir(Info* info){
    info = (Info *)malloc(sizeof(Info));
    info->val=10;
}
```

Comment: O correcto 'e usar `int main()`. O uso de `void main()` limita, desnecessariamente, o teu programa a implementacoes que aceitem essa forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void main(){
    Info* info;
    inserir(info);

    //O erro acontece na linha de baixo, como se o
    //que foi feito na função inserir não persistiu de fato
    //na estrutura
    printf("%d\n", info->val);
}
```

O que acontece aqui é que a variável info não muda de valor antes e depois da função `inserir()`.

O valor inicial da variável (lixo por não ter sido inicializada) é o valor que vai ser utilizado no printf.

Como sugeres na tua resposta, podes resolver atribuindo um valor antes de chamar a função; ou em vez de passares o valor passas o endereço.

```
int main(void) {
    Info *info;
    inserir(&info);
    printf("%d\n", info->val);
    free(info);
}
void inserir(Info **x) {
    *x = malloc(sizeof **x); // falta validacao
    (*x)->val = 10;
}
```

Ainda outra solução é usares o valor de retorn da função

```
int main(void) {
    Info *info;
    info = criarinfo();
    printf("%d\n", info->val);
    free(info);
}
Info *criarinfo(void) {
    Info *x;
    x = malloc(sizeof *x); // falta validacao
    x->val = 10;
    return x;
}
```

**Na minha opinião a tua solução é a melhor!**
Repara que nas duas soluções acima o `malloc` e o `free` estão em sítios distintos. Torna-se muito mais fácil de gerir a memoria quando a função que faz o `malloc` 'e responsável por também fazer o `free`.

Comment: Eu não consegui ver que tinha que passar o ponteiro do ponteiro, vlw. Agora sei quando usar ponteiro do ponteiro rsrs.

Comment: Boa solução no código. Poderia dizer na solução escrita que é por que o parâmetro do tipo `(Tipo *variavel)` só é capaz de escrever por referência no alias para qual o penteiro aponta, e que quando se utiliza `malloc` na função, tenta-se atribuir um novo valor de ponteiro, e não somente alterar o alias dele.

Comment: @RafaelBluhm: sem usar o conceito de referência eu disse mais ou menos isso. O conceito de referência (e aliás) não faz parte integrante do C: é um estrangeirismo do C++.

Comment: Na verdade quis falar que o valor da variável poderia ser mudada diretamente, já que basicamente um ponteiro é uma forma de se fazer referência à objetos na memória. Fui economizar palavras e acabei sendo mal interpretado. Onde falo "referência" leia-se "simulação de passagem por referência".

Answer (score 1):

A solução para este problema foi alterar o local do malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int val;
}Info;

void inserir(Info*);

void main(){
    //A mudança está aqui
    Info* info = (Info *)malloc(sizeof(Info));
    inserir(info);

    printf("%d\n", info->val);
    free(info);

}

void inserir(Info* info){
    info->val=10;
}
```

Pelo que entendi estava passando um ponteiro de estrutura vazia sem endereço de memória para a função `inserir`.  Se eu estiver errado porfavor comentem.

Comment: Nao te esquecas de libertar a memoria quando ja nao for necessaria. Neste caso, faz `free(info);` depois do `printf`.

Comment: bem lembrado, é que fiz um resumo do problema e aqui esqueci do free, o código original é um outro.